# Nuxt 3: How can I use SVGs in the assets directory with object tags

Tags: svg, nuxt.js, nuxt3

The Nuxt 3 [assets documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/assets) states that files in the `assets` directory can be included via the `~/assets` path, for example:

```html
<img src="~/assets/icons/info-circle-solid.svg" />
```

Which works great. However I also want to use `assets` for SVGs and include them with the `object` tag:

```html
 <object data="~/assets/icons/info-circle-solid.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />
```

Nuxt does not seem to auto-detect / transform these for the `object` tag. This is the rendered HTML:

```html
<object data="~/assets/icons/info-circle-solid.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
<img src="/_nuxt/assets/icons/info-circle-solid.svg" aria-hidden="true">
```

Is there a supported way to do this for `object`?